# i am getting an AttributeError

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, k-means

when I run  the following code I the above error,
in following code I am trying to make clusters. pls help me rectify this error this error.

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

dataframe = {
'x':[12, 20, 28, 18, 29, 33, 24, 45, 45, 52, 51, 
     52, 55, 53, 55, 61, 64, 69,  72],
'y':[39, 36, 30, 52, 54, 46, 55, 59, 63, 70, 66, 
     63,58, 23, 14, 8, 19, 7, 24]
     }

df = pd.DataFrame(dataframe)
np.random.seed(200)
k = 3

plt.style.use('seaborn')
centroids = {
i+1: [np.random.randint(0, 80),
       np.random.randint(0, 80)]
for i in range(k)
}

b = centroids.keys()
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5, 5))
plt.scatter(df['x'], df['y'], color='k')
colmap = {1:'r', 2:'g', 3:'b'}
for i in b:
   plt.scatter(*centroids[i], color=colmap[i])
plt.xlim(0, 80)
plt.ylim(0, 80)
plt.show

def assignment(df, centroids):
    for i in b:
        df['distance_from_{}'.format(i)] = (
            np.sqrt(
                (df['x'] - centroids[i][0]) ** 2                 
              + (df['y'] - centroids[i][1]) ** 2 
            )
    )
centroids_distance_cols =['distance_from_{}'.format(i) for i in b]
df['closest'] = df.loc[:, centroids_distance_cols].idxmin(axis=1)
df['closest'] = df['closest'].map(lambda x: int(x.lstrip('distance_from_')))
df['closest'] = df['closest'].map(lambda x: colmap[x])
return df
df = assignment(df, centroids)
df.head()

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5, 5))
plt.scatter(df['x'],         
df['y'],color=df['closest'], alpha=0.5,edgecolor='k')
for i in b:
    plt.scatter(*centroids[i], 
            color=colmap[i])
plt.xlim(0, 80)
plt.ylim(0, 80)
plt.show
```

This is the full error message:
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'lstrip'

The code worked when I tried to run it yesterday but today I came across this error

Comment: If code stops working over nigth then the most likely explanation is that something was changed in the code. If you do not know about it and nobody has access then the most likely explanation is that it was you and forgot the change you made. The solution for that is a versioning system, which will allow you to compare todays non-working version to the most recent working one. When you see the change you will remember having applied it.

Comment: Please explain  what you expect if you do `.lstrip('distance_from_')` on an object and why you think that the `x` allows that use.

Answer (score 0):

The indentation in your function definition is out of place!!

I tried this and it worked:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

dataframe = {
'x':[12, 20, 28, 18, 29, 33, 24, 45, 45, 52, 51, 
     52, 55, 53, 55, 61, 64, 69,  72],
'y':[39, 36, 30, 52, 54, 46, 55, 59, 63, 70, 66, 
     63,58, 23, 14, 8, 19, 7, 24]
     }

df = pd.DataFrame(dataframe)
np.random.seed(200)
k = 3

plt.style.use('seaborn')
centroids = {
i+1: [np.random.randint(0, 80),
       np.random.randint(0, 80)]
for i in range(k)
}

b = centroids.keys()
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5, 5))
plt.scatter(df['x'], df['y'], color='k')
colmap = {1:'r', 2:'g', 3:'b'}
for i in b:
   plt.scatter(*centroids[i], color=colmap[i])
plt.xlim(0, 80)
plt.ylim(0, 80)
plt.show

def assignment(df, centroids):
    for i in b:
        df['distance_from_{}'.format(i)] = (
            np.sqrt(
                (df['x'] - centroids[i][0]) ** 2                 
              + (df['y'] - centroids[i][1]) ** 2 
            )
    )
    centroids_distance_cols =['distance_from_{}'.format(i) for i in b]
    df['closest'] = df.loc[:, centroids_distance_cols].idxmin(axis=1)
    df['closest'] = df['closest'].map(lambda x: int(x.lstrip('distance_from_')))
    df['closest'] = df['closest'].map(lambda x: colmap[x])
    return df
df = assignment(df, centroids)
df.head()

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5, 5))
plt.scatter(df['x'],         
df['y'],color=df['closest'], alpha=0.5,edgecolor='k')
for i in b:
    plt.scatter(*centroids[i], 
            color=colmap[i])
plt.xlim(0, 80)
plt.ylim(0, 80)
plt.show
```

[image]

Comment: When I ran the above code it worked the first time but after I ran it a couple of times I started getting the same error.

Comment: @Shrivardhana Please check indentations, i'm not getting errors after running it for 4-5 times.

Comment: @ Suhas Mucherla i copied your code and ran it in jupyter notebook, but i still got the attribute error